# Should I re-charge battery when it has 90% of juice remaining?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, charging

I always keep my charger plugged-in and my battery remains fully charged.
but sometimes when I restart my laptop it starts charging again and shows the battery is in it's 90's%. My question is should I leave the charger plugged-in so that it reaches 100% again or I plug-out the charger and use the battery to some level and then plug-in the charger?

In simple words,
At which level should I recharge my laptop battery? Is it ok to plug-in the charger at 90% charge remaining?

Comment: Plug it in. Maybe windows doesn't know the real battery %... I've seen very recent windows tablet that wouldn't update the battery life properly. Turning them off when the battery's 100% charged, then waiting a few days (until the battery runs down a little, 20%-30%, plugging it in but not turning it "on" shows the battery graphic - like a cell phone - with the battery closer to half empty) and starting windows has windows thinking the battery's still at 99% or 95% _and charging_, but the battery % would _go down_ while the battery actually charged, eventually the % would start going up again.

Answer (score 2):

I've found good documentation on Battery University: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

The most useful parts for you being, probably, the following:

> The worst situation is keeping a fully charged battery at elevated
>   temperatures. Battery packs do not die suddenly, but the runtime
>   gradually shortens as the capacity fades.

and

> The question is asked, “Should I disconnect my laptop from the power
>   grid when not in use?” Under normal circumstances this should not be
>   necessary because charging stops when the Li-ion battery is full. A
>   topping charge is only applied when the battery voltage drops to a
>   certain level. Most users do not remove the AC power, and this
>   practice is safe.
>
> Modern laptops run cooler than older models and reported fires are
>   fewer. Always keep the airflow unobstructed when running electric
>   devices with air-cooling on a bed or pillow. A cool laptop extends
>   battery life and safeguards the internal components. Energy Cells,
>   which most consumer products have, should be charged at 1C or less.
>   Avoid so-called ultra-fast chargers that claim to fully charge Li-ion
>   in less than one hour.